# How to correctly process queries with parameters

Tags: node.js, express, request

I have two js files in 1st i send query :

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var debug = require('debug')('smsAPI');
module.exports = {
  sendSMS : sendSMS
}
//number 7xxx-xxx-xx-xx
//text any
function sendSMS(number,text) {
  debug('send sms to '+number+'with text'+text);
  request.get(
    'http://127.101.100.3:3200/?'+
    'user=USER1'+
    '&password=coolPSWRD'+
    '&to='+number+
    '&text=Code '+text+
    '&from=news'+
    '&answer=json'+
    '&type=8')
  .then(response=>{
    debug(response);    
  }).catch(err=>{
    debug(err);
  });
}
```

In second file i want get this query but can't :

```
const express = require('express')();

express.get('/',function(rq,res){
  console.log(rq);
  var par = rq.query;
  console.log(par);
  res.send('<h1>Hello world</h1>');
});

express.listen(3200,'127.101.100.3',function(){
console.log('Start');
});
```

In this case i get "RequestError: Error: socket hang up"
If in 1st file i replace `'http://127.101.100.3:3200/?'+...` to `http://127.101.100.3:3200/` it's work.
I'm new to the web, please explain how correctly this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started working after I replaced :

```
    request.get(
    'http://127.101.100.3:3200/?'+
    'user=USER1'+
    '&password=coolPSWRD'+
    '&to='+number+
    '&text=Code '+text+
    '&from=news'+
    '&answer=json'+
    '&type=8')
```

To :

```
var options = {
method:'GET',
uri: 'https://gate.smsaero.ru/send',
qs: {
     user:'USER1',
     password:'coolPSWRD',
     to:number,
     text:'Код подтверждения '+text,
     from:'news',
     answer:'json',
     type:8 
    },
headers:{
        'User-Agent':'Request-Promise',
        },
json:true
};
request(options)
```